# Is it justifiable to spoil a series over placing a title "too off"?

Tags: discussion

I started like 5 months ago watching Game of Thrones with a friend of mine.
So it comes we are right now in season 6 episode 8.

But as I'm a software developer and somewhat required to use Stackoverflow for my work, I feel like already knowing the whole plot of season 7 so far just by the Hot Network Questions that get spammed with titles revealing the plot of the latest episode each Monday.

What I'm doing every time I see such an post, as I for my part got already spoiled: I open that post (without reading the OP to avoid additional spoiling!) and edit the title to be more vague while not changing the meaning. (Of course I can't do this in respect to the post itself).

I understand that a title in general should be meaningful. But is it really more important to have a meaningful title over not spoiling users that maybe don't even want to read about whats going on at movies&tv?

The specific reason I'm asking this is this suggested edit I made: https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/66552

While I understand that my suggested title "Why did this villain performed his attack this way?" is very vague, and would generally agree that this isn't a good edit, I see no better way of getting rid of the spoilers in the title "Why did the Night King attack the furthest target first?" Since from my S6E8 point of view even the Night King engaging in direct combat with others is already a spoiler which ruined the tension of that series for me. In addition the fact that he is 'attacking the furthest target' lets me just by spoilers from previous Monday morning HNQ titles assume that it is likely one of the dragons being attacked.

And from my point of view its not fair that I just by performing my monday morning work get the information that in a series I enjoy watching, in S7E6 The Night King is engaging one(or multiple?) dragon(s) in an attack.

And now the crucial point, even more I think that

### it isn't fair that others are exposed to this kind of spoiler just to not make a title too off the point.

Or am I wrong here and simply have to accept that my leisure time activities will get spoiled, when I'm using stack exchange at work?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64239/discussion-on-question-by-zaibis-is-it-justifiable-to-spoil-a-series-over-placin).

Answer (score 6):

What's a spoiler to you many not be a spoiler to others and SE has **no method** of determining an individual users knowledge level.

> What is a spoiler is inherently subjective. That's why we need to find a reasonable middle ground based on common sense. If you don't know that something is a spoiler without having seen the film, it's not a spoiler.
>
> <sup>[@Napoleon Wilson in Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64239/discussion-on-question-by-zaibis-is-it-justifiable-to-spoil-a-series-over-placin)</sup>

As you know, we try to avoid spoilers in titles but some level of detail is necessary otherwise all the question titles literally become ... *"Why did this character do this?"* and that helps no-one.

There are various things that *you* can do to alleviate the issue though but these will involve hiding all or some of the HNQ questions from view.

There is a script option [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) which amongst many other useful things allows you to hide the Hot Network Questions module.

Alternatively, a Script/CSS option using a custom theme extension like [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) to target the `#hot-network-questions` element in the HTML and hide it from view (if you know CSS).

There are even [Custom Scripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90885/can-you-filter-out-certain-se-sites-from-the-hot-questions-list) to block **individual** SE Sites from your HNQ module.

These and other are discussed on the main [Meta.StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224108/prevent-questions-with-movie-tv-shows-game-spoilers-from-appearing-in-the-hot-qu)

Overall, this is a personal thing for each user... they have to take resposibility for what they see and what they do not wish to see.